# Auto play youtube error?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, youtube

```
    - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)YouTubePlayer {
    UIButton *b = [self findButtonInView:YouTubePlayer];
    [b sendActionsForControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (UIButton *)findButtonInView:(UIView *)view {
    UIButton *button = nil;

    if ([view isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        return (UIButton *)view;
    }

    if (view.subviews && [view.subviews count] > 0) {
        for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
            button = [self findButtonInView:subview];
            if (button) return button;
        }
    }

    return button;
}
```

This code is not working, i am getting 2 warnings on the line `UIButton *b = [self findButtonInView:YouTubePlayer];` the warnings are :

Local declaration of 'YouTubePlayer' hides instance variable
'SecondViewController' may not respond to '-findButtonInView:'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You should call `[YouTubePlayer view]` in the findButtonInView-method.
2. In your SecondViewController.h-file, add the line `- (UIButton *)findButtonInView:(UIView *)view;`.

Comment: How is this:


 - (UIButton *)findButtonInView:(UIView *)view {
    UIButton *button = nil;
 [YouTubePlayer view];
 
    if ([view isMemberOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        return (UIButton *)view;
    }
 
    if (view.subviews && [view.subviews count] > 0) {
        for (UIView *subview in view.subviews) {
            button = [self findButtonInView:subview];
            if (button) return button;
        }
    }
 
    return button;
}

Comment: Wow. Could you update your question with that, it'll make it alot easier to read..